# Running postman test via newman in command line in TFS build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, postman, tfs-2015

I try to run a Web API [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) test in a TFS build step. Postman has it's own command line tool called [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman). When running my tests in command line on my build server, everything works fine. When trying to run the same command via TFS command line build step, I get the error

> 'specified executable is not a valid application for this os platform'

Note that newman is a npm package which has been previously installed on the build machine.

Comment: I think this a generic error that comes from TFS/Windows and has nothing to do with Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please set the account which you succeed to run the command as the
   build agent services account.
2. Restart the build agent service
3. Add a **npm** task before the **Command Line** task to install the
   **newman** within the build process. Reference below screenshot.

Try it again.
[image]

Comment: @nboisvert Have you resolved your issue by this workaround?

Comment: Yeah. The main problem was my version of TFS. TFS 2015 update 1 doesn't have Arguments textbox input